# trying to install civicim on azure Wordpress

Tags: install

I am trying to install civicrm 5.62.1 with mysql 8.1 on azure wordpress web app. It fails with "could not connect to database" and "could not determine if mysql has InnoDB support". I have already tried the patch to the install script

$conn = $this->connect($server, 'username@com1group-mysqldbserver.mysql.database.azure.com', 'your password');

Thanks